# Nuxt 2 axios post call failing with Network Error

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios, nuxt.js

I am working on a Nuxt 2 pizza ordering site. To insert an order, I use an axios post call with 7 parameters, but it obviously is the wrong format, because the call fails and I am getting 7 times the alert 'Network Error'. If I include less parameters in the call, the alert is displayed exactly as many times as there are parameters (Produktnaam/ProduktId .. Hashcode etc.)

I use the following Javascript for the axios post call:

```
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/addbestelling', {
          Produktnaam: this.Produkt.Produktnaam,
          ProduktId: this.Produkt.Produktomschrijving,
          Prijs: this.prijs,
          Soort: this.Produkt.Produktafbeelding,
          Grootte: this.Produkt.Afmeting,
          Aantal: this.aantal,
          Hashcode: this.guid
        })
          .then((response) => {
            const mess = response.data.Message
            alert(JSON.stringify(mess, undefined, 2))
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            alert(err)
          })
```

The API route I am calling is from a Node.js Express API running on localhost, and the /addbestelling route has the following (test) code:

```
        // INSERT Bestelling
        app.route('/addbestelling')
        // GET endpoint
        .post(cors(), async function(req, res) {
            const pool = await PoolPromise;

            var pn = req.query.Produktnaam;

            res.json({ Message: pn });

            console.log('you did an api request /addbestelling !');
        });
```

The axios module I am using is simply axios, with the following import statement:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'Bestel',
```

The API route call is not logging anything to the console.

-- UPDATE --

Hi there

It is fixed now I am using fetch() instead of axios(). I do this:

```
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/addbestelling'

        const data = {
          Produktnaam: this.Produkt.Produktnaam,
          ProduktId: this.Produkt.Produktomschrijving,
          Prijs: this.prijs,
          Soort: this.Produkt.Produktafbeelding,
          Grootte: this.Produkt.Afmeting,
          Aantal: this.aantal,
          Hashcode: this.guid
        }

        fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: qs.stringify(data)
        })
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
          })
          .then((data) => {

          })
```